# ¿Cómo controlar logout automatico en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el sistema Auth de Laravel y estoy complicado con un error que me estaádando cuando la aplicación cierra sesión sola.

Tengo una opcion en el Layout principal que solo la muestro cuando estoy logeado como admin:

```
@if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')) // AQUI DA EL ERROR
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/users/create" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="fa fa-circle-o nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Ingresar Usuarios</p>
                </a>
              </li>
@endif
```

Y el error que me manda cuando se deslogea (Y esto lo asumo porque tengo que volver a logear), es este:

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function hasRole() on null (View:
```

> "Call to a member function hasRole() on null"

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que me deslogee automaticamente o poder controlar ese error?

Intente cambiando a SESSION_DRIVER=database en el archivo .env que encontre como supuesta solución en esta web, pero no me sirvio.

Answer (score 0):

Para «controlar» el tiempo que la sesión puede permanecer inactiva (o como lo llama el OP: logout automático), se utiliza el parámetro `lifetime` en el archivo config/session.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,
```

---

Ahora, para «controlar» el error que muestra el OP viene la siguiente solución:

Si el usuario no ha iniciado sesión o esta ya caducó, `Auth::user()` no estará definido por lo cual dicho error aparece.

Lo más sencillo es verificar antes si el usuario tiene su sesión activa (por medio del método `check()` y posteriormente comprobar el rol:

```
@if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
```

Comment: Haciendo testeos me di cuenta que la configuración del archivo config/session.php la aplicación no la toma en cuenta. Al final funciona cuando lo configuro en el archivo .env, especificamente en la linea SESSION_LIFETIME=120, (con SESSION_DRIVER= por lo que vi es lo mismo).

Comment: Por lo visto no conoces muy bien Laravel, la configuración de la sesión **sí** es tomada en cuenta. Revisa https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Session/SessionManager.php#L30 y https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php#L197

Comment: Si, la verdad soy novato, pero recien testie poniendo `'lifetime' => 1,` en session.php y no paso nada luego de transcurridos varios minutos. Deshice la configuración de session.php y probe seteando SESSION_LIFETIME=1 en el archivo .env y al minuto ya habia caducado mi sesión.

Comment: Son dos cosas muy distintas, por favor revisa el código de Laravel para que entiendas como funciona.

Answer (score 0):

La solución es usar `Middleware`, es un mecanismo que filtra las peticiones HTTP que llegan a tu aplicación.
Laravel te provee de un `middleware` de autenticación por defecto llamado `auth`, este middleware te provee con un filtrado básico, si la ruta a la que tratas de acceder tiene este middleware asignado, automáticamente detecta si tienes sesión activa, sino te manda al login y una vez que inicias sesión te regresa a la ruta que intentabas acceder, para asignar este middleware debes de realizar lo siguiente en tu archivo `routes/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/tu-ruta', 'UnControlador@index')->name('nombre.ruta')->middleware('auth');
```

Si quieres que este middleware aplique para más de una ruta puedes agruparlas y aplicarle el middleware a todo el conjunto:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'otro_middleware_si_es_necesario'])->group(function () {
   //Aquí irían tus rutas
});
```

También puedes crear middlewares personalizados que yo creo será tu caso ya que por los métodos que estás ocupando para los roles, estás usando una librería de permisos (creo que es la de Zizaco/Entrust o la de Spatie Roles).

Para crear uno personalizado basta con ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan make:middleware ChecarSesion
```

Y quedaría algo así, por ejemplo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ChecarSesion
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!auth()->check()) { 
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo le des una leída a la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware) oficial sobre este tema en específico y de acuerdo a tu versión de Laravel que estés usando.

**Es una buena práctica hacer este tipo de filtrado de sesión caducada por un middleware, ya que poner una verificación de sesión activa en la vista sólo para quitar el error haría a que estén dentro de tu aplicación sin sesión y te ocasionará problemas.**

Comment: Si solo es una pequeña sección de la vista la que se desea mostrar u ocultar, ¿para qué un middleware?

Comment: @Shaz Estoy de acuerdo, pero si le está dando un error de que el usuario no existe porque caducó la sesión, significa que no está validando que haya sesión en toda la aplicación, pero sí, si se desea ocultar una sección dependiendo del rol, pues sólo con una condición, y más bien, el título de la pregunta dice "cómo controlar el logout automático", lo que da a entender que va más allá de ocultar una sección en la vista.

Comment: Si nos fijamos en el título, entonces tampoco estás respondiendo a la pregunta.

Comment: @Shaz Sí, porque por lo que logro ver, la persona está un poco confundida y realmente no quiere quitar el logout automático, en realidad el piensa que la solución es quitar el logout automático, por eso después en la descripción añade este detalle: "¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que me deslogee automaticamente o poder controlar ese error?", hacer énfasis en "poder controlar ese error", ya que eso es lo ideal. No le encuentro de ninguna manera la razón por el "-1".

Comment: @Shaz La verdad es que las dos respues me sirvieron. La de Shaz me sirvio para controlar el error y luego darme cuenta que estaba en el layout principal sin estar logeado. A partir de ahi la respuesta de Aarón me sirvio muchisimo tambien. Le agradezco a ambos.

Comment: @Shaz Asumo por lo que escribe, realmente no estoy adivinando, si aquí "¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que me deslogee automaticamente o poder controlar ese error?" sólo hubiera puesto "¿Hay alguna forma de evitar que me deslogee automaticamente?", entonces si tendrías razón, pero el OP no sabe bien cual es la mejor solución y también lo digo por experiencia, al igual que quiero que le quede un proyecto bien y no sólo evadir el problema.

Comment: @tabano De nada, estamos para ayudarnos.